# How can my S-Corp sign up to pay for health insurance on my behalf?

Tags: taxes, usa, insurance

I have created an S-Corp for which I am the sole owner/employee. I understand, according to [this article](https://www.peoplekeep.com/blog/how-s-corporation-owners-can-deduct-health-insurance-expenses) that as the owner of the S-Corp I cannot get health insurance tax-free, but if the insurance policy is set up by the S-Corp and paid by the S-Corp, I can still avoid paying FICA (Medicare tax), FUTA (unemployment tax), and Social Security.

How do I have my S-Corp sign up for health insurance? I tried going to healthcare.gov, but that would've signed me up, not my S-Corp. I tried going directly to Medica, but it says I have to be an authorized broker to sign up. I'm not sure what I have to do.